# iPhone6 view size is smaller with autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, iphone-6

[image]

I have added autolayout but no size class.. I get this in iPhone 6 simulator..

Comment: Add a Splash/Launch screen for iPhone 6.

Comment: Only If there was some way to turn a comment into an answer. thanx..

Comment: didn't get "Only If there was some way to turn a comment into an answer". Should I post answer instead of comment with more description? or Need any other help?

Comment: I meant.. If there was a way to turn a comment into an answer, I would have done that. You solved my problem. thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the Launch Image for iPhone 6. For Launch Image sizes please have a look into bellow link.

[iOS Human Interface Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html)